# Firebase Database Storage Size Limits

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Do Firebase Database and Firebase Storage have limits? If yes, what are they?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Firebase has the basic free bundle plan, also called ***Spark***, which includes the Realtime Database and File Storage Services.

Realtime Database:

- Simultaneous connections: 100
- GB Stored: 1 GB
- GB Downloaded: 10 GB/month

File Storage:

- GB Stored: 5
- GB Downloaded: 1 GB/Day
- Uploads: 20k/Day
- Download: 50k/Day

There are other premium plans like ***Flame*** and ***Blaze***, which has higher offers. See the [Official Firebase Pricings page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) for more details.

Comment: "GB Downloaded: 10 GB" per month?

Comment: @PatrykG I'm not sure, but I think it is per month. If you scroll down on the Official Pricings page, you'll see a Calculate Estimated costs section where the label used in the total is *Estimated **monthly** cost*. But I suggest contacting [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/) just to be sure.

Comment: I contacted Firebase Support, they confirmed, limits are per month.

Comment: @PatrykG Thanks for sharing it here. Cheers!

Comment: Is this limit per developer account, per project or per user connected to the storage?

Comment: @filipst do you have your answer?

Comment: @LongRainbow no, I don't

Comment: @AL Simultaneous connections

Comment: Simultaneous connections you mean firebase project or firebase connected apps or firebase user logins?

Comment: No, 1 GB of storage for Realtime Database is not written which is monthly.